# AS3 PrintJob start() Chrome 21.0.1180.60 m Prints SWF not added Page

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, google-chrome, printing

Code that had been working is suddenly not.

Printing works fine in all browsers even Chrome on MAC( Chrome v: 21.0.1180.57 > which reports up to date.  )

A movieclip is being added via AddPage.  Then printed.

Expected behavior is that the movieclip is printed as it is in other browsers.  Instead the SWF itself is being printed even when bypassing Chrome's print preview and using the standard one.

Any ideas?  The generic code is below.  The code isn't as important.  This has worked for several thousands of users for a few months.  Chrome issue popped up yesterday.

```
if(myPrintJob.start()) {

     if (myPrintJob.addPage(containerElement, rect, options)){
          pageCount++;
     }

     Provider.testProvider("service.userPrinted", dataStr, userPrintedResult, onFault); 

     if (pageCount > 0) {
          myPrintJob.send();
     }              
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Up:

Other users reported the same bug.  It has been flagged as "started" by Google Engineers.
One claims he has a fix.

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=141082
See comment below:

> Comment 11 by viettrun...@chromium.org, Aug 24 (2 days ago)
>
> Probably, the people who are using the AS3 PrintJob API and are seeing
>   this problem are forgetting to call .send() once their done. (This
>   confuses Pepper Flash into doing a "normal" print, rather than
>   forcibly completing the still-open PrintJob and printing that.)
>
> Nonetheless, I have a change to make it work....
>
> Status: Started